# Remove Fans From a Facebook Page Through Graph API

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-page

Manually, I can remove fans from a Facebook Page by going to settings>banned users>people who like this, and clicking remove & ban permanently. Is there an equivalent way to do this through Graph API besides just banning them?

Answer (score 4):

There's no way to do this via the Graph API. Deleting on the `/user/likes` edge is not possible:

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.2/user/likes#delete